# No suitable injection on Material Dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular17, material-dialog

I'm working on a simple dialog to edit a user's data in Angular 17. The thing is that, when I try to inject data from the parent component, an error displays in VSCode that says:

> No suitable injection token for parameter 'data' of class 'UsersCrudModalComponent'. Consider using the @Inject decorator to specify an injection token.

This is the code right now:

Parent:

```js
editUser(uuid: string) {
    const user: IUser | undefined = this._users.find((f: IUser) => (f.uuid = uuid));
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(UsersCrudModalComponent, { data: { user: user } });
}
```

Dialog:

```js
constructor(
    private readonly _dialogRef: MatDialogRef<LoginModalComponent>,
    private readonly _usersService: UsersService,
    private readonly _translate: TranslateService,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: { user: IUser },
) {
    this.user = this.data.user;
}
```

On the other hand, if I move the `@Inject` line to be the first one in the constructor injections, I get this error:

> Unable to resolve signature of parameter decorator when called as an expression. Argument of type '0' is not assignable to parameter of type '3'.

I suspect it's related to typescript version, but I don't see anything odd.

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": ["ES2022", "dom"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

angular.json

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "gaia-spa": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss",
          "standalone": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "standalone": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "standalone": false
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/gaia-spa",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": ["./node_modules/crypto-js/crypto-js.js"],
            "server": "src/main.server.ts",
            "prerender": true,
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": ["src/assets"]
            },
            "ssr": {
              "entry": "server.ts"
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "gaia-spa:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "gaia-spa:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "gaia-spa:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": ["zone.js", "zone.js/testing"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "(private)"
  }
}
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "gaia-spa",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "start:dev": "ng serve --configuration development",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "serve:ssr:gaia-spa": "node dist/gaia-spa/server/server.mjs"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^17.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/ssr": "^17.0.5",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.14.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.5.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.2.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-webstorage": "^13.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^17.0.5",
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.8",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.18.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.2.2"
  }
}
```

I modified the tsconfig.json, changing `experimentalDecorators` from true to false. Now the first error doesn't appear anymore, but I still have the *"No suitable injection token for parameter 'data' of class 'UsersCrudModalComponent'. Consider using the @Inject decorator to specify an injection token."*

Comment: In parent user: IUser | undefined  and in inject user: IUser... so it should be user: IUser  | undefined

Comment: It looks like that doesn't like it either, now I have an error on parent component that says that *No overload matches this call* while in the dialog component keeps saying the same

Comment: Does the error occur only in VSCode or also in compilation?

Comment: In compilation happens too

Comment: @LiraLunaris possible to replicate in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/fptwtw?file=src%2Fexample%2Fdialog-data-example.ts,src%2Fexample%2Fdialog-data-example-dialog.html) and share in the question?

Comment: @NarenMurali I've been trying to make it give the same error but I'm not able, which makes me more confuse since everything looks the same (aside from the imports in the @ component declaration. I tryed to reorder the components and it gives out an "*Unable to resolve signature of parameter decorator when called as an expression.   Argument of type '0' is not assignable to parameter of type '3'.*" which makes me think it might be thing of the typescript version, but it's the same as in the stackblitz... I think I might be missing to add a configuration somewhere, I'm at lost for real

Comment: @LiraLunaris revert the code to last working state, then take some time to check the stackblitz imports for all the files, it must be due to a missing import, take a break, delete node modules and do a fresh npm install and maybe check the typescript version/ restart the code editor, hope your issue resolves soon!

Comment: @NarenMurali Your idea was that it solved it in the end, I don't have any idea as to where this error came from, but after tons of attempts at changing node and typescrypt versions, I went back to the last commit I did (I thankfully didn't lose much) and now works perfectly fine. I'm genuinely dumbfounded, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying to change typescrypt and node versions, I gave up and ended up trying to go back to the last commit, download the node_modules again and now it doesn't show any error.

Also, I must say I didn't have a good version of both typescript and node for Angular 17 according to the official documentation.

My current code is like this right now:

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "gaia-spa",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "start:dev": "ng serve --configuration development",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "serve:ssr:gaia-spa": "node dist/gaia-spa/server/server.mjs"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^17.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/ssr": "^17.0.5",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.14.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.5.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.2.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-webstorage": "^13.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^17.0.5",
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.8",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.18.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.2.2"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": ["ES2022", "dom"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```